# Search by part of word with solr dismax

Tags: search, solr, dismax

How i can search by part of word with dismax?
For example when my query is "wor" i want get results with "**wor**d" "**wor**ld" "ad**wor**ds" etc. fields values.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for [EdgeNGramFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) filter

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" side="front"/>
```

EdgeNGramFilterFactory generates edge grams for the token e.g.

`word` would generate -> `wo, wor, word .....`

You can use this at index time to generate the tokens.
So when you search for `wor`, documents with `word` would match

However, if you want to search in the mid of the words check for [NGramFilterFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/3_6_0/org/apache/solr/analysis/NGramFilterFactory.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question. How be with integer and date types? Do you know solution for it?

Comment: treat the number as string with edge gram filter applied.